# Reliably use \overline in minted code

Tags: math-mode, align, code

How can I (reliably) use `\overline` in minted code? For example, these work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintinline{ocaml}{escapeinside=??}
\begin{document}
\ocamlinline|test ?$\overline{n}$?|

$\ocamlinline|test ?$\overline{n}$?|$

\[
  \ocamlinline|test ?$\overline{n}$?|
\]
\end{document}
```

And these do not:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintinline{ocaml}{escapeinside=??}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{\ocamlinline|test ?$\overline{n}$?|}
\]

\begin{align*}
  \ocamlinline|test ?$\overline{n}$?|
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The inconsistency is confusing to me. I wonder if there is a reliable way to use `\overline` in the code typeset by minted?

Comment: `\mintinline` and derived commands cannot really be arguments to other macros; they *can* work, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the only solution out there is `\Verb` from the fvextra package. It does not have syntax highlighting but avoids all other issues.